# how to install opengeo-postgis-shapeloader in ubuntu

Tags: postgresql, postgis, shapefile

I installed POSTGIS on Ubuntu but it doesn't have a shape file loader. I looked it up online and people say use `sudo apt-get install opengeo-postgis-shapeloader` or `sudo apt-get install opengeo-postgis2-shapeloader` . I tried both and ubuntu said can't locate package opengeo-postgis-shapeloader. How can i install it?
thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can follow this http://suite.opengeo.org/4.1/installation/ubuntu/install.html
to install the mentioned packages